# How often should I water a Skimmia japonica 'Rubella'?

Tags: watering

How often should I water a Skimmia japonica 'Rubella'?

Comment: I know your question is short, but could you please have a more descriptive body? You can add a picture of the plant or describe how old it is, tell us how much you're watering it right now, etc. A question which has the exact same words in both the title and the body is a sign of a poor question...

Comment: Is this plant in a pot, and is it inside or outside? I'm assuming it is potted, or, where you live, you wouldn't be worrying about how often to water it at this time of year.

Answer (score 2):

That depends where you are and your soil conditions. Since Skimmia japonica is in USDA zone 7-9 and is from low elevation forest in east asia. I would say water it about every three days to once a week when it is established and water when the soil seems kind of dry during hot weather (80F and above). If you have mulch you can water less, since it keeps the ground moist for longer periods